# data loss when I use a free rig character in Maya

Tags: maya

Every time I extract a  free rig character in Maya -no matter which version I use-  this  error rises:
"error have occurred while reading this scene that may results in data loss. please check the script editor for details"
This error causes  Rig loss[image]

Comment: Well what does the script editir say then? Anyway this is slightly offtopic.

Comment: This appears to be a software support question rather than a graphic design question. Perhaps consider contacting AutoDesk Maya for support, or perhaps check their user forum to see if others have had the same problem.

Comment: @joojaa this is what script says : "Warning: file: C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2017/scripts/startup/rememberViewportSettings.mel line 29: Active stereo does not work with Aero enabled. Active stereo has been disabled." and " Error: file: C:/Users/mehranb/Downloads/Compressed/New folder (4)/CGTarian-Ray-2018-10-02/CGTarian-Ray-2018-10-02.ma line 5: Unknown Maya file version: 2017ff05. "

Comment: @mehran560 those warnings shouldnt affect your results in any way.